# How to stop css animation without returning to the initial state?

Tags: css, animation

I need to make the play-pause in the animation without js.

Now when I press the pause. Animation goes to the initial state.

How to reset the animation and then restart from the current state?

The solution to javascript is exist. I would like a solution on css.

```css
#play {
  display: none;
}

#play+label[for=play] {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #37A000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#play+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(2),
#play:checked+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play] {
  background: tomato;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}

.progress {
  height: 15px;
  background: #555;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:after {
  width: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #37A000;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play]~.progress:after {
  animation: animProgress 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animProgress {
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="play" id="play">
<label for="play">
  <span>Play</span>
  <span>Pause</span>
</label>

<div class="progress"></div>
```

Comment: Doubt it is possible only in css

Comment: @Morpheus I do not understand you?

Comment: https://translate.google.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the animation to the `.progress::after` with initial `animation-play-state: paused`, then use the :checked for `animation-play-state: running`

```css
#play {
  display: none;
}

#play+label[for=play] {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #37A000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#play+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(2),
#play:checked+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play] {
  background: tomato;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}

.progress {
  height: 15px;
  background: #555;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:after {
  width: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #37A000;
  animation: animProgress 7s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;

}

#play:checked+label[for=play]~.progress:after {
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes animProgress {
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="play" id="play">
<label for="play">
  <span>Play</span>
  <span>Pause</span>
</label>

<div class="progress"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer is complete copy of @delinear answer

Comment: I just realised that, seems we wrote at the same time.

Comment: @Morpheus is there a way to know who wrote it first? I have no problem deleting the answer if he did first.

Comment: not sure. Need to wait which one hits 4 hour mark first :D

Comment: @Morpheus that's a bummer :( guess the OP saw mine first, as that's the one he selected as solution. But not sure why the other has more votes (maybe more people like you thinking I copied it?) I'm pretty sure it's just coincidence, 99% of our code is really copied from the OP and we both made the only change that could possibly fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Move your animation styles into the main :after block and then just switch pause/running when the play button is checked/selected, like so:

```css
#play {
  display: none;
}

#play+label[for=play] {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #37A000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#play+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(2),
#play:checked+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play] {
  background: tomato;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}

.progress {
  height: 15px;
  background: #555;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:after {
  width: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #37A000;
  animation: animProgress 7s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;  
}

#play:checked+label[for=play]~.progress:after {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes animProgress {
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="play" id="play">
<label for="play">
  <span>Play</span>
  <span>Pause</span>
</label>

<div class="progress"></div>
```

Comment: Nice one! Completely forgot about the `animation-play-state`

Comment: Thanks.․․․․․․․․․․